# Transform projects to nuget packages

Tags: c#, nuget

I have a solution of 30 projects that I'd like to publish as 30 NuGet packages.

What's the easiest way to transform project dependencies to package dependencies?

Comment: Actually you do not have to modify you projects to depend on nugets if you do not want to. If you will develop those libs as single solution doing so will actually be painful. The nuget package generator is smart to recognize project reference and nuget generated for that reference and will not publish this dll.

Comment: I'm not sure if my question is clear. Assuming that we have a project A that depends on a project B. I want to publish them as a package A that depends on the package B without editing csproj files

Comment: @atrwsr project references should already advertise their dependencies - is that not working?

Answer (score 2):

Its perfectly OK to create `nuspec` files for all `csprojs` and not modify project to depend on nugets. Nuget will detect `nuspec` files for project references and will not bundle dlls for them if you have package dependency in you `nuspec`.

for example I have done so in my [project](https://bitbucket.org/palpatine/querygenerator/src/master/Qdarc.Queries.Linq/):

nuspec

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>QDARC.Queries.Linq</id>
    <version>1.0.3-alpha</version>
    <authors>Rafał Furman</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>TSQL extension for AST model for SQL queries.</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency id="QDARC.Utilities" version="1.0.6" />
        <dependency id="QDARC.Queries.Model" version="1.0.3-alpha" />
        <dependency id="QDARC.Sql.Connector" version="1.0.3-alpha" />
        </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Release\netstandard2.0\Qdarc.Queries.Linq.dll" target="lib\netstandard2.0" /> 
  </files>
</package>
```

and csproj fragment

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Qdarc.Sql.Connector\Qdarc.Sql.Connector.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Qdarc.Queries.Formatter\Qdarc.Queries.Formatter.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Qdarc.Queries.Model\Qdarc.Queries.Model.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

And you can inspect [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/QDARC.Queries.Linq/1.0.3-alpha) and it contains only single dll.

Comment: This works fine, but the only problem is that I have to maintain nuspec files all the time

Comment: Yes, its a pain that could be mitigated using some scripts that will update version on release. It was not that annoying for me to write it but I can see myself doing that in the future.